# PHP CodeIgniter URL navigation issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to CodeIgniter and also have average PHP knowledge. Just started learning CodeIgniter last week and having a basic problem which i can't overcome. my development environment is (OS,PHPStorm,MAMP,APACHE). CI project root is http://localhost:63342/CodeIgniter/ and this address loads my 'default_controller' (login.php in Controllers folder). this controller redirect me to my view "$this->load->view('login_view');". in my view i have a form with this line:  which supposed to take me to my form.php in Controller upon the form being submitted but it does not! when i submit i am taken to a url : http://127.0.0.1/CodeIgniter/form with error message "connection attempt to 127.0.0.1 was rejected.".

Also when i try to type a url (i.e. BASE_URL()./index.php/form) or amy other URL in fact, i get errors too. i was under impression that navigating through pages in CI is as simple as typing the name of the file and the method in it in my Controller folder. what am i missing here? any attempt to navigation through URL i get "404 Not Found" error. i am sure i am missing something very simple here but i can't figure out what. i have read the documentations and search the web and no answer is found. i have changed the .htdaccess in root, tried the enable mode in Apache, done all the necessary changes in Config.php , routes.php etc. i would appreciated it if you can tell what am i doing wrong here. i wasn't expecting getting started with CI to be this hard  :s

cheers

Comment: In codeigniter 3 versions it is best to set your base url example:  `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/your_project/';`  even though not a requirement but will run into some errors if leave it blank.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you "loose" the port (63342) when you redirect. What is the action of your form? If this is an url like "http://localhost/CodeIgniter/form", you should add the port : http://localhost:63342/CodeIgniter/form

Answer (score 0):

You can output set your login form's action by using the URL helper.

```
site_url('form')
```

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html?highlight=site_url#site_url